# Exiting whole bash script

Tags: bash, exit

I have two script, script1 have a while loop, script 2 called in this while loop. in script 2 is case statement with an exiting whole program option. however when the exit 0 called it only exit from script 2 not exit while loop in script 1. Any idea to do that? script details as below
script1.sh

```
while read -r line;
do
  bash script2.sh
done<list.txt
```

script2.sh

```
read input </dev/tty
case "input" in 
  e)
    exit 0
    ;;
  *)
    echo $input
    ;;
  esac
```

To be clear what I want the program to run is when I press e I want the whole program stop not just finish one loop.
Thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 3):

Script 2 is in a different process to script 1, so script 2 can't kill script 1.

2 Solutions:

1. Make script 2 run in the same process as script run (e.g. `. script2`)
2. Make script 2 return a value that script 1 can check for and exit if matched.

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
set -e
```

at the beginning of script 1. And in script 2, replace 'exit 0' with 'exit 1'.